# Which $[0,\infty]$-categories are compact and connected metric spaces?

Tags: metric-spaces, category-theory

The title says it all.

Which $[0,\infty]$-categories, regarded as generalized metric spaces, correspond to connected metric space? Which categories correspond to compact spaces? (I have a guess for this second question: they are Cauchy complete categories with a property that resembles having a generator).